# Unable to install Neo4J on Mac M3

Tags: docker, macos, neo4j

System and OS : Apple Silicon Mac M3, Sonoma OS

Trying to install neo4j with docker and getting below errors:

ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@2b037cfc' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Some jar procedure files are invalid, see log for details."
Attaching a log file for more reference.

I tried googling and found a few solutions for the problem, but none of them worked for me. Can someome please help me out here?

[Logs for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wz7Pw.jpg)